# Identity Server 5 "error while loading user profile metadata"

Tags: active-directory, wso2

I've installed WSO2 Identity Server 5.0 and have configured a secondary user store with Active Directory. It is able to pull in users as I can see them under Users and Roles. However when I click on a users' profile the Identity Server comes back with "Error while loading user profile metadata".

Any ideas?

Comment: More info from the logs:

Comment: org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,1] Message: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.

Comment: TID[-1234] [IS] [2015-03-23 13:25:10,551] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.identity.user.profile.ui.client.UserProfileCient} - org.apache.axiom.om.OMException: javax.xml.stream.XMLStreamException: ParseError at [row,col]:[3,1] Message: An invalid XML character (Unicode: 0x0) was found in the element content of the document.

Answer (score 0):

Have you made any changes in the `<IS_HOME>/repository/conf/claim-config.xml` or the `<IS_HOME>/repository/deployment/server/userstores/<userstore_domain_name>.xml`  ?

If so please double check if there are any invalid characters in it.

This is possible in the scenario where invalid characters are present.